# Regular Expression in JS for numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression in javascript that takes care of this:

Accept only numbers between 6 and 15 digits, 6 is the minimum.
Numbers cannot contain groups of repeated digits, such as 408408 or 123123
Numbers cannot contain only two different digits, such as 121212

I started with this, then I was loss

```
^[0-9]{6,15}$
```

Comment: More examples needed.

Comment: why regex?why not simple loop?

Comment: yes could be as well, but I thought regex is better

Comment: `Numbers cannot contain groups of repeated digits, such as 408408` I'm pretty sure this is impossible with regex. I have an idea that might work, but it'll probably be simpler to do this with plain procedural code. It's also vague; would 3914475 count because the 4 is repeated?

Comment: yes because 4 is repeated

Comment: Is this for a password policy? If so, I strongly urge you to remove that rule. Banning repeated digits will significantly reduce the number of allowed passwords, making passwords easier to guess. It will actually make the password *less* secure.

Comment: did you want to match this `123453` ? What do you mean by group of repeated characters? How many charcaters are allowed in that group?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: This shouldn't be getting downvoted. The requirements are more or less clear, the English is fine, and it's within the Q/A format. It's only a wrongheaded question if our assumptions about OP's purpose are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have the first rule correct:

   ```
   ^\d{6,15}$
   ```

   That covers both the 6-15 length requirement and the fact that it has to be numeric.
2. With the next rule, it's easier to test for repeated substrings than to test for their absence:

   ```
   (.+)\1
   ```
3. The last one is a lot more complicated. Here's how you test for at least 3 distinct characters:

   ```
   (.+)(?!\1)(.+)(?!\1|\2).
   ```
4. Put it all together and what do you get:

   ```
   ^(?=\d{6,15}$)(?!.*(.+)\1)(.+)(?!\2)(.+)(?!\2|\3).+$
   ```

That answers your question as written, but as I said in the comments, you should consider very carefully whether you're **starting from the right assumptions.** You don't have to use regex for this, nor do you have to do it all in *one* regex. Will the pattern above be easy for you to work with when you come back in 6 months and have to change the rules?

More importantly, if you're trying to make sure users pick a strong password, the rules you're using will *weaken* your security by reducing the number of possible choices. And the maximum length of 15 characters suggests you're storing passwords in plain text. You should be hashing them.

Comment: Thank you Justin for all your comments

Comment: @rgx71 - Glad I could help. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just a Regex, use a combination of if-statements and a RegEx.

```js
function validateNumber() {

  var numbers = document.getElementById('numbers1').value;

  if (numbers && !isNaN(numbers)) {
    // make sure a that something was entered and that it is a number

    if (numbers.length < 6 || numbers.length > 15) {
      // make sure number is between 6 and 15 digits
      alert('Number must be between 6 and 15 digits long.');
    } else if (numbers.match(/(.+)\1+/)) {
      // make sure that the numbers contain no repeated digits
      alert('Number cannot be repeated.');
    } else {
      alert('Number validated!');
      // otherwise, the number is validated
    }
  } else {
    // if no number was entered
    alert('Please enter a number.');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="enter numbers" id="numbers1" />
<input type="button" value="Validate!" onclick="validateNumber()" />
```

Comment: thank you everybody for the answers. I'll review these validations and see what's better to implement in this case.

Comment: An please accept the answer that works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt, just for the challenge:

```
^(?!\d*?(\d+?)\1)\d{6,15}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iB9oP9/4)

- The `(?!\d*?(\d+?)\1)` part will make sure there are no groups of repeated digits by matching a group of digits and trying to match the same digits immediately after. If it finds one, the match fails.
- If you want to allow two same consecutive digits, replace `(?!\d*?(\d+?)\1)` with `(?!\d*?(\d{2,}?)\1)(?!(\d)\2*(\d)(?:\2|\3)*$)`. This will then make sure there are more than 2 different digits by matching a series of one digit, then a different digit followed by a series of a combination of both digits. If it reaches the end of the string it forces the match to fail.

But it'll be probably more maintainable to just do it the conventional way, without regex.

Comment: Looks like we came up with an almost identical answer independently. Have a +1.

Comment: Actually, wait...I'm curious why you edited your pattern, is there something I'm missing? It looks like this one doesn't enforce the "at least 3 distinct digits" rule, but the original did.

Comment: @JustinMorgan I realized you actually cannot have less than 3 different digits without repeating a group anyway ;) That's why the alternative solution changes the rule so that a group is at least 2 digits. (enjoy your +1 too)